# JQuery Mobile - data-iconpos not working in navbar

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, icons, jquery-mobile-navbar

Is there a way to change icon position on navbar's buttons? I am trying to use data-iconpos="left" but that doesn't impact the buttons in navbar.

EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED

Ahhhh. Got it! It was my own mistake.

I was actually applying data-iconpos="left" to individual buttons. After applying that to navbar the problem was solved.

Thanks anyway for responding.

Comment: Pls post html markup and jQM version.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the navigation container has data-role="navbar" attribute. its structure should look something like this:

`<div data-role="navbar"> <ul><li>...<li></ul> </div>`

more info here: [jQuery Mobile nav Demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)